# Where can I find an existing implementation of sprintf?

Tags: c++, printf, implementation, glibc

I need to customize c++ `sprintf` function, after step into `sprintf`, i got `_cfltcvt_l`, but there isn't `_cfltcvt_l` source code in visual studio.

I did the same thing in g++, it lead me to `__mingw_vsprintf` function, but i don't know where `__mingw_vsprintf` is.

I know that [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is one of the implements, after downloaded, i can't find any file related to `sprintf`, So could anyone tell me where can I find an existing implementation of `sprintf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a train of functions to follow in glibc:

First, there's [`sprintf`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdio-common/sprintf.c;hb=HEAD) which calls [`vsprintf`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libio/iovsprintf.c;h=b6cc6b3fa156b92b15cbbac595fd781d07d7d2cd;hb=HEAD) which calls [`vfprintf`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;hb=HEAD) which does all the work. I believe the `io` and `_IO_` prefixes might be irrelevant. They might not be, in which case my answer is wrong.

---

On the MinGW-w64 side of things the train follows a different path:

First, you have [`mingw_sprintf`](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_sprintf.c), which calls `__pformat` or [`mingw_pformat`](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_pformat.c) which looks like it does all the work.

---

I never got to figuring out how BSD libc is structured, so I can't show you their implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you find the specific file so quick? I mean how to search for a function in http://sourceforge.net/ or https://sourceware.org

Comment: @user1024 well, I started from @Ofir's file link, and then followed logical subdirectories (io, libio, stdio-common) until I found something that resembled what I was looking for. There is a search box, but only for commits, so you'll have to sift through them until you get a relevant filename. Note I am not 100% sure of the glibc codepath, it just seems like the logical thing to happen. The MinGW-w64 case was actually quite fast to find: mingw-w64-crt/stdio/ and everything was there already. You can always clone the repositories and search on your local copy using e.g. `grep` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Seems this is what you searching:
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdio-common/sprintf.c;hb=HEAD

Comment: In your link, `sprintf` actually calls `vsprintf` , but still, i can't get `vsprintf` source code.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;hb=HEAD